# AVerTV Hybrid Volar Q

Tags: usb, hardware, tv-tuner

I have recently received a AVerTV Hybrid Volar Q USB TV tuner and it works great in Windows. However, I am unable to get Ubuntu to detect it. I would appreciate hearing from anyone who has managed to use this device with Linux.

Comment: Could you paste the results of `lsusb`.

Answer (score -2):

The results of lsusb are below and as you can see the TV-tuner is listed. Unfortunately, that is as far as it goes. The adapter is not recognised by any apps. It's just sitting there so tantalisingly close yet completely out of reach.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:a005 Dell Computer Corp. Internal 2.0 Hub

**Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07ca:0837 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc. H837 Hybrid ATSC/QAM**

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8103 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 350 Bluetooth

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b97:7762 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 SmartCard Reader

Comment: Sorry. Are you the same McBill as the one who made this question? If so I think you should use your old profile to continue editing your answer and thus receive the proper support. If you can't gain access (somehow) to your previous account you should close (or delete) this question and ask a new one in order to continue the support. Thank you.